# Easiest way to store a list a my own class in a android app?

Tags: android

What is the best/easiest way to store a list (LinkedList) of a class which I created in an Android application?

In apps in other plattform it could be done using:

- a ORM framework
- the database
- serilization and store the file

But my question is: Which of those 3 is the easiest to implement it in an Android application without using a lot of time to make this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using directly SQLite in my opinion is the easiest and most straightforward way to do it. I would consider an ORM-Framework only if I have a lot of classes to store. But I am assuming that's not your case.

Straight serialization to a file might be a good idea, but I would prefer **SQLite** to have the possibility of using database versions, adding indexes and performing more complex search on the data easily.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you inted to use this data. Simplest way is inherit you class from Serializable and dump LinkedList to a file. This works great if you don't need random access to elements of this list.

SQLite is good and flexible but it requires much more coding effort.